# What is the meaning of Caffe - Blob Class - member variables?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, caffe, conv-neural-network

In *Caffe*, as we can see in **blob.hpp**, there are 6 member variables in each blob object:

data_

diff_

shape_data_

shape_

count_

capacity_

**data_** contains  the normal data that we pass along

**diff_** is gradient computed by the network

Since there is no comment in the source code and due to lack of the official documentation, I wanted to know, What is the exact meaning of the others?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**shape_data_** & **shape_** represent the same thing. The only difference is that their types are different. **shape_** is a vector of integers with the dimensions of the data, whereas **shape_data_** is a shared pointer.

**count_** is the total number of elements in **data_**. So it the product of all the dimensions in **shape_**.

**capacity_** is the maximum size of **data_** that can be accommodated in the Blob.

References:

- http://blog.luoyetx.com/2015/10/reading-caffe-2/
- http://imbinwang.github.io/blog/inside-caffe-code-blob

Comment: Thanks for your reply.